# How to get rid of TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead?

Tags: python, flask

I can't understand why TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead.
I tried to process the variable selected_years through ','.join... but the error does not go away.

**Functions of database connection and query execution**

```
# Database connection function
def get_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    return conn

# Function of query execution
def execute_query(query, params=None):
    conn = get_connection()
    # Create a cursor object to run PostgreSQL commands in the database
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # query
    cur.execute(query, params)
    # To access the generated fetch we use cur.fetchall()
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    # close cursor
    cur.close()
    # closing the connection
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

**Variable processing and sql query**

```
selected_years = [int(i) for i in request.form.getlist("year") if i.isdigit()]
selected_stations = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("station")]
selected_indicators = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("indicator")]
columns = columns_list + [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("columns")]
        query = ("SELECT {} FROM fact_table WHERE year = ANY(%s) AND indicators = ANY(%s) AND station_name = ANY(%s);"
                    .format(",".join(["\"{}\"".format(c) for c in columns])),(selected_years, selected_indicators, selected_stations))
        rows = execute_query(query, (selected_years, selected_indicators, selected_stations))
```

Earlier my code looked like this, and everything worked with variable processing as it is done now (but there was a problem with idle in transaction, well, and in general I decided that it is better to make connection with database in a separate function).

```
def index():
    # database connection
    with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
        # creating a cursor object to run PostgreSQL commands on the database
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fact_table;") 
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
    
    If request.method == "POST":
        With psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            # creating a cursor object to run PostgreSQL commands on the database
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_table WHERE year = ANY(%s) AND indicators = ANY(%s) AND station_name = ANY(%s);"
                        .format(",".join(["{\"{}\""".format(c) for c in columns])),(selected_years, selected_indicators, selected_stations)))
            # To access the generated fetch we use cur.fetchall()
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
```

Can you please tell me what my mistake is?